# html-javascript: page refreshes whenever an event is fired

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have an html page with buttons and such, to which I assign event listeners. Whenever one of the buttons is clicked, the page goes back to its original state, as if the browser had been closed and opened again. So if I have text fields into which I've inputted some info, they will be cleared as soon as a button is clicked, even if its event listener does nothing.

Likewise, if I include this event listener into the html, `<body onload="pageLoaded();">`, the pageLoaded() function will be called whenever a button is clicked.

Why is this happening, and how can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are using submit buttons, which will submit the form they are in unless you cancel the default action.

```
eventObject.preventDefault();
```

See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3aevent.preventDefault).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your click event listener was added to a link or a button within a form. If so, you may add `return false` a the end of the listener to prevent the default behaviour being executed.

```
var link = $("#mybutton");
link.click(function() {
    alert("clicked");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the button type to "button" will resolve this issue. The default type is "submit" which as the others have said will submit the form.

```
<button type="button">Button</button>
```